# Repair IMEI of a rooted Motorola Moto E4

Tags: motorola, imei

I have rooted my Motorola Moto E4 (XT1765, MetroPCS, Qualcomm processor - Not MTK) on Android 7.1.1 with Magisk. Now I want to repair its IMEI.

I've tried Miracle Thunder and many other tools, but nothing worked. When I try the Miracle Thunder tool to repair IMEI, after a restart, the baseband becomes null or unable to check IMEI.

Can you please suggest a method to repair its IMEI?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve null baseband, flash the same baseband files:

```
fastboot flash modem NON-HLOS.bin
fastboot erase modemst1
fastboot erase modemst2
fastboot flash fsg fsg.mbn
fastboot reboot
```